# React error trying to upload a txt file passing the name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, upload, fetch

I have a component that loads a txt file and then I am trying to upload that txt file passing the name on the request, I got the file like this:

```
const fetch = ({ target }) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      reader.readAsText(file);
      reader.onloadend = e => {
        setFileContents(e.target.result);
      };
    }
  };
```

and I am trying to upload it like this:

```
const URL = 'myURL';
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', fileContents);
                fetch(URL, {
                  method: 'PATCH',
                  headers: // ... my headers,
                  body: formData
                })
                  .then(response => response.json())
                  .then(data => {
                    // success
                  })
                  .catch(() => {
                    // error
                  });
```

This approach works but, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) `formData.append(name, value, filename);` is allowed, but if I do this:

```
 formData.append('file', fileContents, 'myFile');
```

the browser's console yells:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'

how can I get over this? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little more Google and I post this solution hoping that anybody can use it:

Since `fileContents` is a string I needed to turn it into a File, I did this:

```
const myBlob = new Blob([fileContents], { type: 'text/plain' });
const myFile = new File([myBlob], { type: 'text/plain' });
```

then

```
formData.append('file', myFile, 'myFile');
```

Works like a charm. So please, if there is a better way to do this, let me know.